# Logic used in if statement using Exclamation Mark beside function

Tags: php, logic

This is some code from [w3schools PHP](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_filter_advanced.asp) and involves validating data.

**This has been bugging me for hours.**

But the question here is about the if statement they used; why did they use an Exclaimation Mark (!) before the `filter_var()` function. It doesn't make sense to me from a logical perspective, what exactly does the statement ask because im pretty sure that the `filter_var()` function is not boolean.

```
if (!filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_IPV6) === false) {
    echo("$ip is a valid IPv6 address");
} else {
    echo("$ip is not a valid IPv6 address");
}
?>
```

Lastly, how does the above if statement work, because in earlier chapters they wrote the following:

```
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
  $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
}
```

Which says "if the email is **NOT** valid, throw an error". However in the code at the top of this question, it says "if the email is **NOT** valid thus returning `false` and this is `===` to `false` throw a success message. Isn't that confusing?

Comment: I think you missed that in your first code there is a `!` at the start of the if statement so if it is NOT valid then it's true and unequal to false so it also throws an error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`filter_var` returns the input value `$ip` if it is valid. A valid IPV6 address is "truthy" (it is a non-empty string). The `!` operator applied to a truthy value produces `false`.

So if `$ip` is valid, then `!filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_IPV6) === false`.

Remember that the `!` has **higher precedence** than the `===`. That's what makes the two code samples in your question different.

---

`filter_var` returns `false` if the test fails, so another perfectly good (and perhaps clearer) way of testing this would be:

```
if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_IPV6) !== false) {
    // $ip is valid
}
```

The second piece of code effectively does the same thing (checking the result of `filter_var` is `false`), although it does so in a less explicit way.

Answer (score 0):

The function : `filter_var()` return a mixed var type, it means 
**String** if it works good;
**Boolean/FALSE** if an error occured;

So the test is correct :

```
if (!filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_IPV6) === false) {
    echo("$ip is a valid IPv6 address");
} else {
    echo("$ip is not a valid IPv6 address");
}
```